# Check if view has been opened in this run

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

How can I check every time the app is launched if a view has been loaded within that single run, not the lifetime of the app?

What I am trying to do is save the position of a map, if the view has never been opened this run I want to preset its location, but if it has been opened this run I want to leave it where it left off and not set it to a preset location.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you loading this view? Are you using an init method?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is the only method I am calling before loading it. Should I look into `initWitNibName...`

Comment: In that case if `viewDidLoad` gets executed your view is loaded, this method only gets called once.

Comment: Yes, how can I make a method only get called the first time a view has been loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Save the map's position in `NSUserDefaults`. On next launch (each launch) , check whether your `NSUserDefaults`  has a value for map's location. If not then, set your preset position. If there is a value, then set that value for map, so it would be the last used location.